# some action with Varien.Tabs

Tags: product, tabs

I want to do few action with Magento tabs

1: `How can i disable tabs`

2: `I have button other than tabs i want that when button is clicked tabs 3 get open automatically`

How can i do it?

Comment: Which tabs do you mean?

Comment: tabs on product detail page, i want that on button click it should goto tab 3

Comment: So this is on frontend. What theme are you using, RWD?

Comment: yeah ..................